# Sticky post for each category on category pages

Tags: categories, sticky-post

I would like to show category.php a post I set as sticky post for that category.

Do you know code to do this?

Comment: Your category archive should already show sticky posts(i think), are you doing any customization with the query in the category template for your theme?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sticky posts 'pop' to the top of an archive (I'm not totally sure) by default

- [Sticky posts for categories](http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2011/01/08/sticky-posts-for-categories/)

Is a link I came across, maybe some helpful stuff in there.... it's a bit much for me to digest, I'll be honest!

Otherwise, I keep seeing this plugin come up in related discussions: [astickypostorderer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/astickypostorderer/)

Not sure if it works with current Wp as its only rated up to 2.9.2

Comment: They may not pop to the top, but they do appear. I am wondering if the question should instead be, **How can i get sticky posts at the top of a category archive**..

Comment: Yeah, that's probably more appropriate.  They do appear, and they keep their classes and stuff, so they would maintain any 'special' formatting.  They just don't 'stick' I guess you would say